# Best way to include a demo project with a CocoaPod?

Tags: cocoapods

I am wondering what is the best way to include a demo project with a CocoaPod. In particular, I want this to a be a component that anyone can try using the `pod try` command.

I see two options:

### option 1: embedded project in Examples/ with a Podfile

Here the Pod contains an embedded project, which uses a Podfile to reference the pod itself.

This is what is suggested by the directory structure produced via the `pod lib create` command, and by the [CocoaPods documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html).

### option 2: embedded project in Demo/ using pod as a resource

Here the Pod contains an embedded project, where the Xcode project file uses a relative path to refer directly to resources from the pod itself.

This is what I see in various examples in the wild, and it is what is working right now in [a Pod I am authoring](https://github.com/algal/ALGReversedFlowLayout).

As CocoaPods is still in flux, I am wondering if one way is more "blessed" than the other. Is the documentation suggesting option 1 out of date? Or is the code supporting option 2 out of date? Will both work with `pod try` going forward?

Answer (score -1):

Please, see as also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396075/is-the-heuristic-cocoapods-uses-for-the-pod-try-command-documented-anywhere) where demo project **search heuristics** are explained.

The best solution is to look through the `def pick_demo_project(dir)` routine in the **try-plugin** source https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-try/blob/master/lib/pod/command/try.rb#L133 to see the actual demo choosing options.

Comment: So to know the best way to include a demo project, the best course of action is to study the cocoa pods ruby source code? Sad.